# Aspx Listbox rows match count issue

Tags: asp.net

I have a strange issue when adding items to a listbox. I want it to adjust it's size to match it's count. When adding 1 all is fine, add the second and the rows go to 4 then after we have more than 4 all is working fine. The other thing is the location of the top of the listbox also moves up a few pixels - wierd. Is this a bug? This is the button event code for adding them. Updated!

```
Dim s As String = tbTest.Text
If Not s = "" Then
  Dim li As New ListItem(s)
  If Not lsbTest.Items.Contains(li) Then
    lsbTest.Items.Add(li)
    Dim i As Integer = lsbTest.Items.Count
    lsbTest.Rows = i
    lsbTest.Height = i * 22
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Is it a windows forms app or a web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Rows property. Let it stretch by setting the CSS height to 100% of a containing div.

UPDATE:

Take a look at this solution (Googled it):

[Allowing listbox to grow vertically....](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=185977)

Comment: Great idea, but I do not have a min-height property in css.

Comment: I've updated answer, play around with it and see if this works?

Comment: Thanks for your help I have set Height:100%; for the Listbox and the div is set to auto. It does not expand with new items.

Comment: Remind me, what html output does the ListBox render as, can you view source and check?

Comment: Setting the height makes the listbox grow, but it remains to have only 1 row.

Comment: I did. That must be for a Windows Listbox - they work that way.

Comment: The problem with your original code is that you need to increment the Rows count when you create the new row. You have it in an entirely separate if block.

Comment: Combination or Rows and height `code` Dim s As String = tbTest.Text
    If Not s = "" Then
      Dim li As New ListItem(s)
      If Not lsbTest.Items.Contains(li) Then
        lsbTest.Items.Add(li)
        Dim i As Integer = lsbTest.Items.Count
        If Not i = 0 Then
          lsbTest.Rows = i
          lsbTest.Height = lsbTest.Rows * 22
        End If
      End If
    End If

Comment: Wished I knew how to put my comments in code tags - not immediately discernible!